# Which corporate companies have funded Ethereum?

Tags: enterprise

Ethereum raised 18 million via crowdfunding, but has any other corporations put funding into Ethereum yet?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's speculative. Major part of the funds was aquired anonymously.

Answer (score 3):

Here's an attempt to answer this question as of February 1 2016, defining Ethereum as the Ethereum Foundation or close to it.  Since Ethereum is a platform, this answer excludes funding that is procured by anyone building something on the platform.  According to the Ethereum Foundation's blog, there have been 3 companies: Microsoft, Wanxiang, and Omise.

### Microsoft

https://blog.ethereum.org/2015/10/28/microsoft-to-sponsor-ethereums-devcon1-2

> Marley Gray, Director of Technology Strategy US Financial Services at
>   Microsoft said, “Microsoft is excited to sponsor and attend Ethereum’s
>   DevCon1. We find the Ethereum blockchain incredibly powerful and look
>   forward to collaborating within the Ethereum Community. We see a
>   future where the combination of Microsoft Azure and Ethereum can
>   enable new innovative platforms like Blockchain-as-a-Service. This
>   will serve as an inflection point to bring blockchain technology to
>   enterprise clientele”.

### Wanxiang

https://blog.ethereum.org/2015/09/28/the-evolution-of-ethereum

> The first of these to announce itself is the Wanxiang blockchain
>   research institute and fund based in Shanghai (yes, this is the “major
>   collaboration” I hinted on recently, and is also my much delayed
>   answer to “how did your China trip go?”), which includes (i) an
>   agreement to purchase 416K ETH, which has already concluded, (ii) an
>   upcoming conference in October, (iii) a non-profit blockchain research
>   institute, and (iv) a $50m blockchain venture-capital fund, all with
>   emphasis on Ethereum development.

### Omise

https://blog.ethereum.org/2016/01/08/d%CE%BEvgrants-update-new-funding

> The good news is that ÐΞVgrants isn’t over, because we now have $100K
>   USD of additional funds to work with through the new year, thanks to a
>   generous donation by Omise.